# .NET Server Scheduling Service - How should I go about this?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I need to create an application that will run on a server and be able to be configured to run commands at certain times.  For instance, there will be a web interface allowing a user to set an engage time and a disengage time.  Once those values have been saved by the user I need for the server to be able to fire off those commands precisely at the time specified each day.

I would also need to be able to set single use non recurring events that would occur... maybe 10 minutes from the time an event was triggered and have a command fired off when that 10 minute timer goes off.

I've already got a class library written that has the engage and disengage commands exposed.  I would hope to be able to integrate this into whatever solution I end up with and simply be able to make calls directly to the class.  Alternatively I could also compile the class library into an executable and have commands issued to it via command line.  I'm hoping to not have to do the latter.

I've never written anything like this before.  I've peeked a bit at Windows Services, but there is a lot of chatter out there saying that it isn't necessarily the best option.  Can someone please guide me in the right direction please?

Comment: You might want to investigate [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest solution:

make a console exe and run under scheduled task in windows.

Let web page to accept user input and modify a configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

A windows service is not a bad idea, its perfect for this kind of application. Unless you end up using standard windows scheduled tasks as the trigger for your command, you need some sort of process that is always running to contain your scheduler. A windows service is an excellent candidate for this.

Using a windows service in conjunction with Quartz.NET and some sort of persistence layer so you can store your schedules (in case you need to restart the service or it crashes etc) would be a good way to go.

Alternatively, you could write an application that just adds and removes windows scheduled tasks, but considering you have existing class libraries, using Quartz.NET will fit in well with your existing libraries.